# I need to ping the list of servers and store their output individually on each server

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I need to ping the list of servers and store their output individually on each server. I have the script to ping but i need assistance in storing the ping status locally on the server /var/opt/pingresult.txt. Script that I have is :-

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

for i in $( cat $HOME/iplist.txt )
do
    ping -q -c2 $i > /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo $i "Pingable"
    else
        echo $i "Not Pingable"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Your existing script seems to do what you want, but writes the output to standard output, correct?  If so, you just need to redirect the output to the file.

Comment: You said `individually on each server` in the title and `locally on the server` in the question - so do you want to save results on each *remote* server or on the machine from which the script is run?

Comment: Actually I need to ping the hostname on the local server itself via ping command and store its output in a file to show as "Pingable" or "Non Pingable".

Comment: ok but this is not what I asked about.